# UIView smooth moving

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview, uiscrollview

If you will move some UIView object with simple code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
int stepInt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].x - [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self].x;
_subView.left += stepInt;}
```

You will see that it twitches while moving. But if you try to move some UIView object placed into UIScrollView, you will see that it's moving very smoothly. So, the question is - how UIScrollView works inside?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you had a look at this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/beginAnimations:context:

Comment: What is it you like to achieve? Having a scrolling functionality in your custom UIView? Or do you just like to know how UIScrollViews work internally? To move things around smoothly consider using UIView animations.

Comment: I have specific task and I can't use UIScrollView or UIView animation.

Comment: Some you are moving a UIView (as a subview of something else), by responding to the user's touch, and it isn't very smooth?

Comment: What are you doing with your calculated value stepInt? Are you adjusting the location of your subview UIView? How, exactly?

Comment: stepInt is just difference between previous and current finger position. I just move it and nothing else. I do NOT perform any calculations while moving (that may slow the process). Just move

Comment: It's not really big twitches. It's hard to see it. You can feel it only if you will place UIScrollView near that view and will scroll it one by one. Also, the view that you move should be big, full screen size. If you will make it small the twitches will go away. So I think it's something with drawRect methods inside the frame work... any ideas?

Comment: can you please vote UP my question? I do not really understand why you voted it down

Comment: @occulus that's what I need to achieve now. I have some uiviews moving on a larger uiview: in the simulator they move perfectly smoothly but in my device (iphone 5) they twitches, overall if they move on a captured image by UIImagePickercController. How can make them move smoothly?